# Why to use override in Inheritance method of c# instead of function

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I wanted to know that while inheritance can be used to inherit properties and methods in derived class.

Why we don't write functions in the derived classes instead declaring them as override.

Following example will explain more about my question.

```
class Net
{
    public virtual void Act()
    {
    }
}

class Perl : Net
{
    public override void Act()
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Perl.Act");
    }
}

class Python : Net
{
    public override void Act()
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Python.Act");
    }
}
```

```
// Use base class and derived types in a List.
List<Net> nets = new List<Net>();
nets.Add(new Perl());
nets.Add(new Python());

// Call virtual method on each instance.
foreach (Net net in nets)
{
    net.Act();
}
```

In above example act function can be declared as "NEW" functions why should we opt for overriding the base function??

> Edit: Suppose i have a case as follow

```
class Net
{
    public virtual void Act()
    {
    }

    public virtual void secondMethod()
    {
    }
}

class Perl 
{
    public override void Act()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Perl.Act");
    }

    public override void secondMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Perl.Act");
    }
}

class Python 
{
    public new void Act()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Python.Act");
    }

    public override void secondMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Perl.Act");
    }
}
```

What should i do then.
In above case i want the base class to be inherited but The functionality i am implementing may be different.
In such cases should i use override or write a complete different method.

Comment: Without any other change, declare any of the child method as `new` and see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new` keyword is used for method hiding, mainly for *versioning* purposes, but note that both methods are still available in derived class! and can be accessed with a simple `cast`. But on the other hand, with method overriding, you override the behavior (this is what we call *polymorphism*), so in a derived class, the overridden method will totally replace the base method, therefore cannot be accessed via an instance of the derived class even with an upcast to the base class! because the virtual method is replaced by the overridden method.
Let me show you this concept with an example:

```
public class Base
{
    public virtual void VirtualMethod() { }
    public void NewMethod() { }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public override void  VirtualMethod() { }
    public new void NewMethod() { }
}

...

Base derived = new Derived();
derived.VirtualMethod(); // Derived.VirtualMethod()
derived.NewMethod(); // Base.NewMethod()
((Derived)derived).NewMethod(); // Derived.NewMethod()
```

Comment: thanks Arin Ghazarian.
This is what i was looking for.

Comment: Other answers are good too, I just tried to explain more fundamental *OOP* concepts. Hope this helped.

Comment: I don't mean to disregard other answers they are good and informative but i was looking for ((Derived)derived).NewMethod(); // Derived.NewMethod() this statement in particular.

Comment: I'm so glad it helped you.

Answer (score 4):

Because without that `virtual` method on your base class you would not be able to call `Act` withing your loop:

```
foreach (Net net in nets)
{
    net.Act();
}
```

And `foreach` is not the only place you can use that. Imagine you have a method called `Foo` which takes `Net` instance as parameter:

```
public static void Foo(Net net)
{
    net.Act();
}
```

You can still pass both `Python` and `Perl` to that method, and they will both execute their own `Act` method logic.

`virtual` is useful everywhere you want to provide some basic, default functionality and be able to `override` that default one within derived classes.

You should read [Knowing When to Use Override and New Keywords (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173153.aspx)

Comment: Yes I know this. I want to know why specifically to use virtual rather than writing a new method.
Is it only to use foreach loop??

Answer (score 1):

> In above example act function can be declared as "NEW" functions why should we opt for overriding the base function

Inheritance is meant to use what base class provide along with extra functionality where necessary. Why would you inherit in first place if you don't want to use the functionality of base class?

Comment: Suppose i have 2 methods in base class  method a and b
I want to inherit method a and I want to write a new B in my derived class.
In this case i use inheritance but should i declare both base methods as Virtual and override them.
Or should i write a new method in the derived class with same name using keyword New

Comment: if you don't want your second method to be overriden then it should not be virtual in first place. consider using interfaces and breaking the required functionality in to seperate interfaces. Unless you give the full picture it would be difficult to answer properly.